# how to upload image in the firebase storage and get uploaded image url in react using swr-firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase for storing data with swr-firestore. so far it's good. Now i need to upload image to firebase storage. how can i do that with fuego of swr-firestore. Any suggestion.
https://github.com/nandorojo/swr-firestore.

using fuego i'm calling node functions in the firebase, using useCollection i'm getting data from the required collection. i'm able to update collection related record data aswell. But I didn't find any example to store imate on firestore. can anyone suggest something.
Thank you

Comment: A classic approach is to store the image in [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage), then get a signed URL that you store in Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

In nextJs uploading image to firebase is done after long searching things.

```
app.tsx
=======

import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/functions'
import 'firebase/storage'
import { FuegoProvider } from '@nandorojo/swr-firestore'
import { Fuego } from '@/utilities/fuego'

const fc = {
apiKey: API_KEY,
authDomain: AUTH_DOMAIN,
projectId: PROJECT_ID,
storageBucket: STORAGE_BUCKET,
messagingSenderId: MESSAGE_SENDER_ID,
appId: APP_ID,
measurementId: MEASUREMENT_ID,
}

const fGo = new Fuego(fc)

const MyApp: React.FC<AppProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
return (
<FuegoProvider fGo={fGo}>
  <Component {...pageProps} />
</FuegoProvider>
)
}

xyz.tsx:
=======
import { fGo } from '@nandorojo/swr-firestore'
const [imageAsFile, setImageAsFile] = useState('' as any)
const onSubmit = async (data: any) => {
if (imageAsFile === '') {
  console.error(`not an image, the image file is a ${typeof 
 imageAsFile}`)
 }
 const fileNewName = new Date().getTime() + imageAsFile.name
 let finalUrl = ''
 const uploadTask = 
fGo.storage().ref(`/mypics/${fileNewName}`).put(imageAsFile)
 await uploadTask.on(
  'state_changed',
  (snapShot: any) => {
    console.log(snapShot)
  },
  (err: any) => {
    console.log(err)
  },
  () => {
    fuego
      .storage()
      .ref('/mypics/')
      .child(fileNewName)
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((fireBaseUrl: any) => {
        if (fireBaseUrl) {
          finalUrl = fireBaseUrl
        }
      })
  }
 )
 }


 return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} autoComplete="off">
            <input
              type="file"
              name="profilePic"
              id="profilePic"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setImageAsFile(e?.target?.files?.[0])
              }}
            />
            <input type='submit' />
    </form>
)

Hi, finally i got how to upload and get back image url. "Renaud Tarnec" 
Tq.
```